# How to add a new property to Redux state when dispatching an action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an initialState in my reducer which is bit of nested.I am trying to add a new property "isTouched" to my state when dispatching an action/state changes.

```
    const initialState = {
     isLoading: false,
     events: [
      { year:2021 , place: [{id:1,name:"BD"}] },
      { year: 2020, place: [{id:2,name:"AMS"}] },
    ],
  };
```

and in my reducer:

```
case types.TOGGLE_PLACE_INFO:
  return {
    ...state,
     here need to write the logic if events.place.id === action.payload then add a new property to 
   "place" like this: place: [id:1,name:"BD",isTouched:true]
   }
```

so after that my state would looks like this:

```
   const initialState = {
     isLoading: false,
     events: [
      { year:2021 , place: [{id:1,name:"BD", isTouched:true}] },
      { year: 2020, place: [{id:2,name:"AMS"}] },
    ],
  };
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-tdd-v3gbd?file=/src/reducers/commonReducer.js
so, when the setTouched button is clicked it should update the place and add isTouched: true

Does anybody know any work around how to implement this logic. Any helps would be highly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's not a valid JS syntax `[id:1,name:"BD", isTouched:true]`, please fix it. And also, do you need to add `isTouched` to **all** places with the payload id?

Comment: I need the isTouched when certain items is matched with the action.payload which is basically an Id, so,in this case: events.place.id === action.payload when action.payload === 1 then isTouched will be added to the first items

Comment: @DennisVash, did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

as Dennis' says, your code isn't valid javascript. you want to store it in an object instead of an array

try something like this:

```
const initialState = {
     isLoading: false,
     events: [
      { year: 2021, place: [ {id:1, name:"BD"} ]},
      { year: 2020, place: [ {id:2, name:"AMS"} ]},
    ],
};

case types.TOGGLE_PLACE_INFO:
  return {
    ...state,
    events: state.events.map((event) =>
              event.id === action.payload.id
                 ? {...event, place: [{...event.place, isTouched:true}]}
                 : event
              )
          }
```

I've changed your initialState so `place` is now valid. im then mapping over all the values and if they match I return the current like so `{...event}` and then adding in the new `isTouched` key like so: `{...event, isTouched: true}`. then secondly if they don't match im just returning `event`

let me know if makes sense. can clarify if not!

Comment: I have edited my question, it's actually objects inside an array

Comment: `event.id === action.payload.id` does that check the id from place or events array?if it checks from the evens array then there is no id, it should check if the id is matched with the place.id

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work: it should be `event.place[0].id === action.payload.id` and `[{...event.place[0], isTouched: true}]`. Of course it's not actually clear why it has to be nested inside an array...

Comment: yeh it wont work now. let me try and update it. why is place an array?

Comment: well, unfortunately, this is the JSON response,I have to deal with at the moment that makes things complex

Comment: @ninja let me know if you still need me to look at this

Comment: it would be nice as still I couldn't make that work

Comment: @RedBaron any helps with this issues?

Comment: hey @ninja sorry been super busy. are you able to make a codesandbox to replicate this that I could then fix for you ?

Comment: Okay, let me create a sandbox and then will get back to you...

Comment: @RedBaron I have added the sandbox link in my question. so,i want to update the state in action type "UpdatePlace". let me know if you have some questions...

Comment: I am a bit confused. what should happen when I click `setTouched` visually?

Comment: When we click to setTouched button it should add "isTouched:true" property in the selected items. Updated the sandbox link a bit where I console the props.events.place after inside the setTouched function

Comment: so visually in the UI it,will not do anything but we can console the new state change